# How to combine MultiPolygons together to simplify a GeoJSON?

Tags: javascript, geojson, turfjs

I have very large GeoJSONs with a lot of Multipolygons. I am able to visualize these shapes on a map using leaflet, however the rendering is really slow since I have too many geometries.
My goal would be to simplify the GeoJSONs by merging together all the shapes that now are overlapping each others, since I don't care to have such detailed shapes.

[example of the rendered map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZugJP.jpg)

I previously tried to use `turf.simplify()`, but the result is really rough and it's not really working nicely. Right now I am naively trying to use `turf.union()` inside a loop to add one shape to the other and obtain a unique shape.

```
 const geojson = data.features
   //I am filtering the features i need
  .filter(feature => feature.properties.Name === ': 30 - 45')
  .map((feature, f) => {
    let present
    let next
    if (f < data.features.length - 1) {
      //I am assigning to the variable I created before the present and next feature in the loop
      present = data.features[f]
      next = data.features[f + 1]
      //I am using turf.js to merge features together.
      return turf.union(present, next)
    }
  })
```

I am not entirely sure this strategy makes sense, if I log the result I just obtain again the data I had previously, as if no merging has been done.
Am I doing something wrong? It's one of my first serious approaches with GeoJSONs and turf, so I am not sure if I am even adopting a good strategy.

Comment: The ideal solution is to minimize the total number of polygons and maximize the number of convex polygon. It is not a simple problem. Worse case, `map` and `turf.union` in your code is mapping every feature to a `MultiPolygon` and it will never eliminate any polygons like you want. Try combining polygons that overlap/collide using `turf.concave` and `turf.convex`

Comment: Yes! this was painful but it works! I extracted all the points and by using `turf.convex` I managed to get a much more simplified shape! It needs fine tuning and probably it's very specific to this type of file. Can I accept your comment? It was really helpful in guiding me :)